# Scraping dictionary entries using python's Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the original sentence and translations e.g. from the following page:

https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=Verwirrung&from=und&to=spa

My current status looks as following:

```
word = "Verwirrung"
url="https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query={}&from=und&to=spa".format(word)
vstr=requests.get(url).content
Soup = BeautifulSoup(vstr,features="html.parser")
rows = Soup.findAll('div',{"class":"sentence-and-translations md-whiteframe-1dp"})
for row in rows:
    if "Verw" in str(row):
        print(row)
```

However, this returns nothing.
The idea is to iterate over every entry, however each entry is wrapped in a div tag and loads of "quot" signs which I'm not sure how to find or filter for. The first entry is nested within it's div tag as following:

```
 <div ng-cloak
 sentence-and-translations
 ng-init="vm.init([], {&quot;id&quot;:922518,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Die Verwirrung spottet jeder Beschreibung.&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;deu&quot;,&quot;langName&quot;:&quot;German&quot;,&quot;script&quot;:null,&quot;dir&quot;:&quot;ltr&quot;,&quot;audios&quot;:[],&quot;correctness&quot;:0,&quot;isFavorite&quot;:false,&quot;isOwnedByCurrentUser&quot;:false,&quot;user&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:6,&quot;username&quot;:&quot;MUIRIEL&quot;,&quot;role&quot;:&quot;advanced_contributor&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:0},&quot;highlightedText&quot;:&quot;Die &lt;span class=\&quot;match\&quot;&gt;Verwirrung&lt;\/span&gt; spottet jeder Beschreibung.&quot;}, [], [{&quot;id&quot;:76623,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;\u305d\u306e\u6df7\u4e71\u5b9f\u306b\u540d\u72b6\u3059\u3079\u304b\u3089\u305a\u3002&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;jpn&quot;,&quot;langName&quot;:&quot;Japanese&quot;,&quot;script&quot;:null,&quot;dir&quot;:&quot;ltr&quot;,&quot;audios&quot;:null,&quot;correctness&quot;:0,&quot;isFavorite&quot;:false,&quot;isOwnedByCurrentUser&quot;:false,&quot;user&quot;:null}])"
 class="sentence-and-translations md-whiteframe-1dp">
```

Is there a good clean way to only iterate over the data?

Comment: turn off JavaScript in web browser and open your link - you will see that it uses JavaScript to add elements - but BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript

Comment: the reason you get nothing is because you have to scrape what's inside javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `row['ng-init']` and you will have all JavaScript but if you remove `vm.init([],` at the beginning (11 chars) and `)` at the end (1 char) and add strings `[` `]` then you get JSON data which you can convert to Python's structure with lists and dictionaries

```
data = '[' + row['ng-init'][11:-1] + ']'

data = json.loads(data)
```

and now you can use

```
print(data[0].keys())

print('DE:', data[0]['text'])

for item in data[1]:
    print('ES:', item['text'])
for item in data[2]:
    print('ES:', item['text'])
```

You have access to other elements using keys

```
'id', 'text', 'lang', 'langName', 'script', 'dir', 'audios', 'correctness',
'isFavorite', 'isOwnedByCurrentUser', 'user', 'highlightedText'
```

Full working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #as BS
import requests
import json

word = "Verwirrung"
url = "https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query={}&from=und&to=spa".format(word)
vstr = requests.get(url).content
Soup = BeautifulSoup(vstr, features="html.parser")

rows = Soup.findAll('div', {"class":"sentence-and-translations md-whiteframe-1dp"})

for row in rows:
    data = '[' + row['ng-init'][11:-1] + ']'
    #print(data)
    data = json.loads(data)
    #print(data[0].keys())
    print('DE:', data[0]['text']) #, data[0]['lang'], data[0]['langName'])
    for item in data[1]:
        print('ES:', item['text']) #, item['lang'], item['langName'])
    for item in data[2]:
        print('ES:', item['text']) #, item['lang'], item['langName'])
```

Result

```
DE: Sie verwirren mich.
ES: Me estás confundiendo.
DE: Verwirre ich dich?
ES: ¿Te estoy confundiendo?
ES: ¿Te estoy liando?
DE: Verwirre ich Sie?
ES: ¿Te estoy confundiendo?
DE: Verwirre ich euch?
ES: ¿Te estoy confundiendo?
DE: Die Berichte waren verwirrend.
ES: Los informes eran confusos.
DE: Es war sehr verwirrend.
ES: Fue muy confuso.
ES: Era muy confuso.
DE: Es kann zunächst verwirrend sein.
ES: Al principio puede ser confuso.
DE: Es ist mitunter zunächst verwirrend.
ES: Al principio puede ser confuso.
DE: Das kann anfangs Verwirrung stiften.
ES: Al principio puede ser confuso.
DE: Oh, jetzt ist es wirklich verwirrend...
ES: Oh, ahora es realmente extraño...
ES: Oh, ahora es realmente confuso...
ES: Ay, ahora sí que está raro...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
link = 'https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=Verwirrung&from=und&to=spa'
browser.get(link)

raw_data = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('text.ng-binding.flex')
for item in raw_data:
    print(item.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Sie verwirren mich.
Me estás confundiendo.
Verwirre ich dich?
¿Te estoy confundiendo?
¿Te estoy liando?
Verwirre ich Sie?
¿Te estoy confundiendo?
Verwirre ich euch?
¿Te estoy confundiendo?
Die Berichte waren verwirrend.
Los informes eran confusos.
Es war sehr verwirrend.
Fue muy confuso.
Era muy confuso.
Es kann zunächst verwirrend sein.
Al principio puede ser confuso.
Es ist mitunter zunächst verwirrend.
Al principio puede ser confuso.
Das kann anfangs Verwirrung stiften.
Al principio puede ser confuso.
Oh, jetzt ist es wirklich verwirrend...
Oh, ahora es realmente extraño...
Oh, ahora es realmente confuso...
Ay, ahora sí que está raro...
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you want is here:

```
<div ng-cloak
     sentence-and-translations
     ng-init="vm.init([], {&quot;id&quot;:5127750,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Verwirre ich dich?&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;deu&quot;,&quot;langName&quot;:&quot;German&quot;,&quot;script&quot;:null,&quot;dir&quot;:&quot;ltr&quot;,&quot;audios&quot;:[{&quot;user_id&quot;:75624,&quot;external&quot;:null,&quot;sentence_id&quot;:5127750,&quot;user&quot;:{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;Oblomov&quot;,&quot;audio_license&quot;:null,&quot;audio_attribution_url&quot;:null}}],&quot;correctness&quot;:0,&quot;isFavorite&quot;:false,&quot;isOwnedByCurrentUser&quot;:false,&quot;user&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:54488,&quot;username&quot;:&quot;raggione&quot;,&quot;role&quot;:&quot;advanced_contributor&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:0},&quot;highlightedText&quot;:&quot;&lt;span class=\&quot;match\&quot;&gt;Verwirre&lt;\/span&gt; ich dich?&quot;}, [{&quot;id&quot;:5127755,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;\u00bfTe estoy confundiendo?&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;spa&quot;,&quot;langName&quot;:&quot;Spanish&quot;,&quot;script&quot;:null,&quot;dir&quot;:&quot;ltr&quot;,&quot;audios&quot;:[],&quot;correctness&quot;:0,&quot;isFavorite&quot;:false,&quot;isOwnedByCurrentUser&quot;:false,&quot;user&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:5127757,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;\u00bfTe estoy liando?&quot;,&quot;lang&quot;:&quot;spa&quot;,&quot;langName&quot;:&quot;Spanish&quot;,&quot;script&quot;:null,&quot;dir&quot;:&quot;ltr&quot;,&quot;audios&quot;:[],&quot;correctness&quot;:0,&quot;isFavorite&quot;:false,&quot;isOwnedByCurrentUser&quot;:false,&quot;user&quot;:null}], [])"
     class="sentence-and-translations md-whiteframe-1dp">
```

So concentrate you efforts here:

```
word = "Verwirrung"
url="https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query={}&from=und&to=spa".format(word)
vstr=requests.get(url).content
Soup = BeautifulSoup(vstr,features="html.parser")
div = Soup.findAll('div',{"class":"sentence-and-translations md-whiteframe-1dp"})
ng_init = div[0]["ng-init"]
ng_init = ng_init.replace("vm.init([], ","").replace("])","")
```

And this gets you nicely formatted senteces, included for free:

```
{"id":5127745,"text":"Sie verwirren mich.","lang":"deu","langName":"German","script":null,"dir":"ltr","audios":[],"correctness":0,"isFavorite":false,"isOwnedByCurrentUser":false,"user":{"id":54488,"username":"raggione","role":"advanced_contributor","level":0},"highlightedText":"Sie <span class=\\"match\\">verwirren<\\/span> mich."}, [], [{"id":2931574,"text":"Me est\\u00e1s confundiendo.","lang":"spa","langName":"Spanish","script":null,"dir":"ltr","audios":null,"correctness":0,"isFavorite":false,"isOwnedByCurrentUser":false,"user":null}
```